# How to save form data in AOR without using Resource component?

Tags: reactjs, admin-on-rest

I'm currently working on a project and using admin-on-rest. The `Resource` component has been very helpful so far, it's so easy to build views to list, view, create and edit items. But there has been coming up some situations, where there isn't a need for the `Resource` component and mapping the API endpoint to certain urls in AOR.

On this project there's a settings page for example changing the website language. Now I also would like to add there a form for editing customer data. The AOR documentation has examples, where `SimpleForm` component is inside `Edit` component, but I can't do it that way, because using it throws errors. I don't know yet the exact reason for those errors, but I guess it is related to that, that I'm not using the `Resource` component that would map the correct API endpoint for the `Edit` component to use.

First I had a problem that how to get the customer data to a `SimpleForm` component without using the `Resource` component. I solved that by adding a rest call to the `componentDidMount` method, and setting the response to the state. Using the state the SimpleForm component can display the correct customer data. The SimpleForm provides a Save button by default, but I also found out that I can override that using a toolbar prop.

My code so far:

```
componentDidMount() {
    restClient("GET_ONE", 'customers', {pagination: { page: 1, perPage: 5 }, sort: { field: 'name', order: 'ASC' }, id: 5})
        .then(response => {
            this.setState({customerData: response.data});
        }
    });
}

render() {
    const FormToolbar = props => <Toolbar>
        <SaveButton label="Save" />
    </Toolbar>;

    return (
        <Card>
            <ViewTitle title="Edit customer" />

            <SimpleForm record={this.state.customerData} toolbar={<FormToolbar />} >
                <TextInput source="name" />
                <TextInput source="email" />
                <TextInput source="street"  />
                <TextInput source="postal_code" />
                <TextInput source="city" />
            </SimpleForm>
        </Card>
    );
}
```

But how should I implement saving the customer details? The save button does nothing currently, maybe because it just doesn't know what to do. Should I create some custom function with rest put call to the customer endpoint? How to bind that function to that save button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use the react-admin components for anything else than resources. It's not an UI kit. In your case, you should use plain old material-ui and implement forms by yourself (validation, submit with fetch, etc.)

Comment: I see variations of this question pop up quite often. Maybe I should take the time and document how to create a custom form.

Comment: Not sure: it's just react ™

Comment: Hehehe. True. But I usually have to copy out a couple of files from the AOR core and go through the Create and SimpleForm code to figure out how to create a custom form.

Comment: Please tell me you're not using react-admin components to build custom forms not handled by react-admin resources... It's not an UI kit :)

Comment: Hehe. Not using it as a UI kit at all. However the form required wiring up with RA internals which requires some functions to be available in the local scope that RA does not export (which I then have to copy from source). And there are differences even between the version I used last (1.4) and the one I am using now (2.XX) so ultimately I think for more advanced use cases some minor documentation can be useful. (I can write this I think btw. Am not working on the UI project presently but will have a custom form ready next week. Can share my steps as soon as I am done)

Comment: These are the save and handleSubmitWithRedirect functions.

Comment: Why are you using them at all ? The `save` function is meant to be used for resources creation and it just calls the redux action creator

Comment: Fair point. I got started with studying the code of the Create Component and stripping away everything that seemed unessential. Maybe this wasn't necessary either. Will try and remove